# Help with computing fractional octave center frequencies

Tags: logarithms

Given frequency X, I want to compute frequency Y, given interval is Z-octaves. Z will normally be fractional.

Y = X + X * 10^log10(Z) returns 33.333 given X=25 and Z=1/3.

I'm expecting ~31.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One octave-up is multiplying frequency by $2$.

---

Correct formula should be:
$$
Y = X\cdot 2^{Z};
$$
for $X=25 $ (Hz), $Z=1/3$:
$$
Y = 25\cdot 2^{1/3} \approx 25\cdot 1.259921 \approx 31.498.
$$

---

For example: 
$1$ octave from $25$ Hz is $50$ Hz; 
$3$ octaves from $25$ Hz is $200$ Hz 
 etc.

Comment: Ah, so I was over-thinking it! This is helpful! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Write $$y=25+25\cdot 10^{\lg(1/3)}$$ and use that $$\lg(1/3)=-\lg(3)$$ and $$\lg(x)=\log_{10}{x}$$